# How to merge FLAC files into single, eventually chaptered, file?

Tags: windows, mp4, flac

Windows Phone doesn't support gapless audio playback, so albums whose tracks are meant to segue into one another are ruined (there's a pause or a click when switching tracks).

I would like to try merging the individual FLAC files into a single file, and ultimately into a chaptered `.m4a` file.

What is the process to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) should allow you to open multiple flac files and output them as a merged file.  Here are some additional instructions that detail the process: [Ehow description](http://www.ehow.com/how_10004299_join-flac-files.html)

Audacity will also allow you to split into chapters and to convert to mp4 format.

Comment: Thank you for the Foobar tip, there may be a way to do it in a single step.

Comment: Very bad idea. Audacity is not lossless.